# How to know if USDZ model has to be placed on the detected plane?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am developing the iOS shopping app and it has the AR feature that users can place the object in the real world using the ARKit & RealityKit.
I have been using Apple's [sample AR project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/environmental_analysis/placing_objects_and_handling_3d_interaction) for the AR feature and it's been working great with horizontal planes.

I have different kinds of AR models - some should be placed on the horizontal plane only, and some should be placed on the vertical plane only.

I can detect the `horizontal`/`vertical` planes but not sure how to know if the model supports the horizontal or vertical alignment.
Any answers are highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In RealityKit, use `.isAnchored` to find out whether your model is placed on the detected plane.

```
if usdzModel.isAnchored {

    print("Model is placed")
    print(anchor.anchoring.target)
}
```

In ARKit, use `anchor(for:)` instance method that searches the scene hierarchy for an anchor associated with the provided node.

```
open func anchor(for node: SCNNode) -> ARAnchor?
```

Inside ARSCNView delegate method use the following logic:

```
let nodeAnchor = sceneView.anchor(for: usdzModel) as? ARPlaneAnchor
    
guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }
            
if nodeAnchor != nil {

    if planeAnchor.identifier == nodeAnchor?.identifier && 
       planeAnchor.alignment == .horizontal {

        print("Horizontal ARPlaneAnchor")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Andy Jazz, thanks for your reply.  Not sure my question was clear but "usdzModel.isAnchored" is just saying that it's the horizontal or vertical model?